# how to use wc_create_order with subscription product

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to create a new order programatically.

This code works well with simple product,

```
    $product = get_product($product_id);
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product( $product , 1 );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    // assign the order to the current user
    update_post_meta($order->id, '_customer_user', get_current_user_id() );
    // payment_complete
    $order->payment_complete();
```

but when i use it for subscription product it does not add the subscription, it only add the order.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's my code for creating a subscription -- it took a lot of trial and error to figure it all out. Best of luck!

```
function create_test_sub() {

    $email = 'test@test.com';

    $start_date = '2015-01-01 00:00:00';

    $address = array(
        'first_name' => 'Jeremy',
        'last_name'  => 'Test',
        'company'    => '',
        'email'      => $email,
        'phone'      => '777-777-777-777',
        'address_1'  => '31 Main Street',
        'address_2'  => '', 
        'city'       => 'Auckland',
        'state'      => 'AKL',
        'postcode'   => '12345',
        'country'    => 'AU'
    );

    $default_password = wp_generate_password();

    if (!$user = get_user_by('login', $email)) $user = wp_create_user( $email, $default_password, $email );

    // I've used one product with multiple variations

    $parent_product = wc_get_product(22998);

    $args = array(
        'attribute_billing-period' => 'Yearly',
        'attribute_subscription-type' => 'Both'
    );

    $product_variation = $parent_product->get_matching_variation($args);

    $product = wc_get_product($product_variation);  

    // Each variation also has its own shipping class

    $shipping_class = get_term_by('slug', $product->get_shipping_class(), 'product_shipping_class');

    WC()->shipping->load_shipping_methods();
    $shipping_methods = WC()->shipping->get_shipping_methods();

    // I have some logic for selecting which shipping method to use; your use case will likely be different, so figure out the method you need and store it in $selected_shipping_method

    $selected_shipping_method = $shipping_methods['free_shipping'];

    $class_cost = $selected_shipping_method->get_option('class_cost_' . $shipping_class->term_id);

    $quantity = 1;

    // As far as I can see, you need to create the order first, then the sub

    $order = wc_create_order(array('customer_id' => $user->id));

    $order->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $order->add_shipping((object)array (
        'id' => $selected_shipping_method->id,
        'label'    => $selected_shipping_method->title,
        'cost'     => (float)$class_cost,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'
    ));

    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->update_status("completed", 'Imported order', TRUE);

    // Order created, now create sub attached to it -- optional if you're not creating a subscription, obvs

    // Each variation has a different subscription period

    $period = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period( $product );
    $interval = WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval( $product );

    $sub = wcs_create_subscription(array('order_id' => $order->id, 'billing_period' => $period, 'billing_interval' => $interval, 'start_date' => $start_date));

    $sub->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);
    $sub->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $sub->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );

    $sub->add_shipping((object)array (
        'id' => $selected_shipping_method->id,
        'label'    => $selected_shipping_method->title,
        'cost'     => (float)$class_cost,
        'taxes'    => array(),
        'calc_tax'  => 'per_order'
    ));

    $sub->calculate_totals();

    WC_Subscriptions_Manager::activate_subscriptions_for_order($order);

    print "<a href='/wp-admin/post.php?post=" . $sub->id . "&action=edit'>Sub created! Click here to edit</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but I can't get it to work. What function is `wcs_create_subscription()`? It's not defined, and neither is `wc_create_subscription()` if it's a typo.

Comment: You'll need the Subscriptions extension for that bit to work! (Don't forget you can google function names, they're usually very easy to find because they're so specific.)

Comment: Yeah, I had the Subscriptions plugin, but it seams like I had an older version(1.5.*). I upgraded to 2.0.* now and the code seams to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool use-case and example of wc_create_order + wcs_create_subscription!

Comment: I keep getting ```Call to undefined method WP_Error::add_product()``` any idea ?

Comment: @Kravitz check what line the error's on, and do `if (is_wp_error($order) var_dump($order)` or same line with `$sub` instead of `$order`, before the call to `add_product()`. That'll tell you what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

```
     $order_data = array(
        'status'        => 'completed',
        'customer_id'   => 1,
        'customer_note' => '',
        'total'         => '',
    );

    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'; // Required, else wc_create_order throws an exception
    $order                  = wc_create_order( $order_data );
```

Comment: please try to avoid code only answer without explaining why they solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you must manually handle creating the subscription through code, as just adding an order does not handle it automatically.

Here's my custom function I built based on all the answers I found on SO and digging through subscriptions code base.

Tested with

- WordPress 5.2.5
- WooCommerce 3.8.0
- WooCommerce Subscriptions 2.6.1

https://gist.github.com/tripflex/a3123052f36daf18f7cb05391d752223

```
function give_user_subscription( $product, $user_id, $note = '' ){
    // First make sure all required functions and classes exist
    if( ! function_exists( 'wc_create_order' ) || ! function_exists( 'wcs_create_subscription' ) || ! class_exists( 'WC_Subscriptions_Product' ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $order = wc_create_order( array( 'customer_id' => $user_id ) );
    if( is_wp_error( $order ) ){
        return false;
    }

    $user = get_user_by( 'ID', $user_id );

    $fname     = $user->first_name;
    $lname     = $user->last_name;
    $email     = $user->user_email;
    $address_1 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_1', true );
    $address_2 = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_address_2', true );
    $city      = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_city', true );
    $postcode  = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_postcode', true );
    $country   = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_country', true );
    $state     = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_state', true );
    $address         = array(
        'first_name' => $fname,
        'last_name'  => $lname,
        'email'      => $email,
        'address_1'  => $address_1,
        'address_2'  => $address_2,
        'city'       => $city,
        'state'      => $state,
        'postcode'   => $postcode,
        'country'    => $country,
    );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'shipping' );
    $order->add_product( $product, 1 );

    $sub = wcs_create_subscription(array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'status' => 'pending', // Status should be initially set to pending to match how normal checkout process goes
        'billing_period' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period( $product ),
        'billing_interval' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval( $product )
    ));

    if( is_wp_error( $sub ) ){
        return false;
    }

    // Modeled after WC_Subscriptions_Cart::calculate_subscription_totals()
    $start_date = gmdate( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
    // Add product to subscription
    $sub->add_product( $product, 1 );

    $dates = array(
        'trial_end'    => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_trial_expiration_date( $product, $start_date ),
        'next_payment' => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_first_renewal_payment_date( $product, $start_date ),
        'end'          => WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_expiration_date( $product, $start_date ),
    );

    $sub->update_dates( $dates );
    $sub->calculate_totals();

    // Update order status with custom note
    $note = ! empty( $note ) ? $note : __( 'Programmatically added order and subscription.' );
    $order->update_status( 'completed', $note, true );

    // Also update subscription status to active from pending (and add note)
    $sub->update_status( 'active', $note, true );
    return $sub;
}
```