# How to subscribe free subscription on user registration in woocommerce subscription plugin?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks, subscription

I am using Woocommerce Subscription plugin. I have two types of Subscription plans right now.

1. Premium Subscription
2. Free Subscription

When any user registers on my site, I want every user to show default free subsciption subscribed to that account in beginning until it upgrades manually later. Is there any Hook which I can use?

I have tried checking in Plugin settings but I didn't find anywhere if I can set a subscription plan 'as default'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create an order, then create a subscription, link the order to the subscription using WooCommerce classes. Below is the link where I found my answer:

[wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/how-to-use-wc-create-order-with-subscription-product)

The response given by Jeremy Warne worked for my website's logical flow.